# I want to know the best alternatives for google optimize

Tags: google-apps

Details about my site:
My site uses react + shopify. We also use google optimize to run AB tests on the site abd universal google anaytics to track events on site.

Since google optimize would be discontinued from september, wanted to know the best alternatives for google optimize that we can use to run AB tests on the site.